# how to make the column name of a table attribute name for another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have 2 tables, T1 has attributes for form as `name,address,rating` with its corresponding control type as `text,textarea,integer` respectively.

In another table T2,i store value from form and has columns `valuechar,valuetext,valueint` into which value of `name,address and rating` is saved in different rows for a single form.Now I want to make query and result the following result from the above two tables.

```
array(
      [name]=>value from valuechar
      [address]=>value from valuetext
      [rating]=>value from valueint
)
```

how do i do this effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you make one table and make those 3 fields?

Anyways; if the results are exactly the same you can do something like this:

```
 $dataArray1 = mysql_fetch_array..? // Table2
 $dataArray2 = mysql_fetch_array..? // Table2

 $data = array();

 for($i = 0; $i < count($dataArray1); $i++) {
    $data = $dataArray1[$i] = $dataArray2;
 }
```

Give me a little more information about what you are trying to achieve and maby we can work something out!

Comment: I am making seperate tables for form values and seperate table for form attributes.Now from sql query I want the form attributes as attribute with its corresponding values.The backend was made this way.Now i just want it in front end.

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch your example code to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: I used mysql_fetch_array as an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy data from one table to another then you can use the following query:

```
insert into t1 
select valuechar,
valuetext,
valueint
from t2
where <some condition>
```

Give us some more information about your requirement.

Comment: Ajith Sasidharan it's not copying data from 1 table to another.'name,address,rating' are different row values of column form_name for T1 and T2 contains its corresponding values in different rows 1 for each.Now by means of sql I want name,address,rating of T1 as attribute and its corresponding value from T2

Answer (score -1):

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-insert-into-select-select-into-table/
may be this will be useful for you

Comment: Links are not answers.  SO answers are expected to stand alone.